# jackrabbit for local file sharing

Tags: java, jackrabbit

Can `Jackrabbit` used for local file sharing?

For example if I have a folder with files in `D://my-folder` and I want to provide other application access to that folder vie `REST` or `SOAP`. Can I use `Jackrabbit` to manage `my-folder`?

Answer (score 0):

No -- that would require a persistence mode where Jackrabbit maps filesystem files to JCR nodes. It's probably possible to implement that, but doesn't come out of the box.

Comment: then what it is for? just some specially formatted storage? virtual file system?

Comment: So basically it is something for already existing file management system. I get it.

Comment: JCR is a Java API for content management systems for hierarchical content. Jackrabbit is an implementation using the JCR API.